# How can I change between a Login/Sign up Form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, containers, jquery-selectors

I'm doing a project where I have to create a website. Currently I am making the Login/Sign up Form, however I don't know how to change between them using a link.

This is my html code for it:

```
  <div class="container">
    <form class="form--unhidden" id="Login">

[...some code is meant to be here to input username/password input + continue button]

    <p class="form__text" id="ToCreateAccount">
      <a class="form__link" href="#ChangeCreateAccount" id="linkCreateAccount">Don't have an account? Create account</a>
    </p>
    </form>
    <form class="form--hidden" id="CreateAccount">

[...some code is meant to be here to create username/password input + continue button]

      <p class="form__text" id="ToLogin">
        <a class="form__link" href="#ChangeLogin" id="linkLogin">Already have an account? Sign in</a>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
```

This is my JavaScript for the code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const loginForm = document.querySelector("#Login");
    const createAccountForm = document.querySelector("#CreateAccount");

,
        e.preventDefault();
        loginForm.classList.remove("form--hidden");
        createAccountForm.classList.add("form--hidden");
    });
    document.querySelector("#ToLogin").addEventListener("click", e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        loginForm.classList.add("form--hidden");
        createAccountForm.classList.remove("form--hidden");
    });
```

I've tried to solve this by adding an id to the class="form__text" line and then connect it to the javascript, and also add # or/and "link" to inside the brackets (e.g. #ToCreateAccount).

```
    document.querySelector("#ToCreateAccount").addEventListener("click", e => {
```

I believe that the problem is that the JavaScript doesn't fully know what's meant to chance, but I can't figure out how to make it understand it.

Hope this is understandable.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You were close. I'm guessing your original code should have had this part:

```
document.querySelector("#ToCreateAccount").addEventListener("click", e => {
```

right after this part:

```
const createAccountForm = document.querySelector("#CreateAccount");
```

Please take a look at the following example. I've added some of the missing elements, and some simple CSS.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var create = document.getElementById("linkCreateAccount");
  var haveAcc = document.getElementById("linkLogin");
  var formLogin = document.getElementById("Login");
  var formCreateAcc = document.getElementById("CreateAccount");

  create.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    hide(formLogin);
    show(formCreateAcc);
  });

  haveAcc.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    show(formLogin);
    hide(formCreateAcc);
  });
});

function hide(elem) {
    elem.classList.add("form--hidden");
    elem.classList.remove("form--unhidden");
}

function show(elem) {
  elem.classList.add("form--unhidden");
  elem.classList.remove("form--hidden");
}
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-family: 'Arial','Calibri',sans-serif;
}
.form--unhidden {
  display: block;
}
.form--hidden {
  display: none;
}
label, input {
  display: block;
}
input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 4px;
}
a.form__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
button {
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background-color: rgb(9, 100, 170);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  outline-style: none;
  outline-width: 0px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
a.form__link:hover {
  color: #aa5810;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <form class="form--unhidden" id="Login" action="loginPage" method="POST">
        <div class="form-inputs">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-inputs">
            <label for="pass">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass">
        </div>
        <div class="form-inputs">
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
        <p class="form__text" id="ToCreateAccount">
            <a class="form__link" href="#CreateAccount" id="linkCreateAccount">Don't have an account? Create account</a>
        </p>
    </form>
    <form class="form--hidden" id="CreateAccount" action="registerPage" method="POST">
        <div class="form-inputs">
            <label for="newUsername">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="newUsername" name="newUsername">
        </div>
        <div class="form-inputs">
            <label for="newPass">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="newPass" name="newPass">
        </div>
        <div class="form-inputs">
            <label for="againPass">Retype password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="againPass" name="againPass">
        </div>
        <div class="form-inputs">
            <label for="newEmail">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="newEmail" name="newEmail">
        </div>
        <div class="form-inputs">
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </div>      
        <p class="form__text" id="ToLogin">
            <a class="form__link" href="#ChangeLogin" id="linkLogin">Already have an account? Sign in</a>
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

The hiding / showing is handled similar to what you were trying to do, I just placed it in a function.